# change automatic positioning of ports

Tags: jointjs, rappid

With Rappid 1.6 trial I used getPortattrs to change the position of the ports.
Instead of attrs[portSelector] = { ref: '.body', 'ref-y': (index + 0.5) * (1 / total) };, I use my own rule.

But with Rappid V2 this is not working any more and I can’t figure out how to do it.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

There is completely new approach to ports since JointJS 1.0 (it's part of the Rappid V2). It should be compatible with shapes from the older versions, however it's recommended to use the new port api instead.

**ports in jointjs 1.0:**

- can be added to any shape (introduced new api on shapes)
- pre-defined layouting functions for port positions and port labels
- better performance

for more information about api visit  http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.0/joint.html#dia.Element.ports

layouting and port positions:  http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.0/joint.html#dia.Element.ports